# Partitioning for 3 Operating Systems

Tags: partitioning

I am getting a new computer and I want to set it up with windows 8 (I'd prefer 7 but it comes with 8,) Ubuntu, and Arch. How would you recommend partitioning a 1 TB hard drive. I would use windows for games only, and Ubuntu while I'm figuring arch out, and that later moving to arch as my primary os. I would like to have a shared partition between arch, and Ubuntu for files I would want on both, but that is not necessary. Thank you for any help.

(If it's of any help it's a 1 TB Drive 5400 rpm, with 8 GB of RAM, and an intel i7 processor)

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning is very personal depending on your needs. My own optimal plan is usually not so good a year or two later as things change.

My suggestion anyway is shrink Windows a lot. I prefer small system partitions so most activity is closer together on drive and larger data partitions. Not sure about your games and if they all can be in a separate NTFS or d: partition.
For Linux I would use generous 25GB for / (root). I keep /home inside root but have all data in data partitions both NTFS and Linux formatted including some normally hidden data like Firefox & Thunderbird profiles. Then I have the same email & bookmarks in all installs.
You can share swap if you do not hibernate nor encrypt systems.

You need to confirm if Arch uses the same UID and GIDs as Ubuntu or you may have sharing issues.